# How to check if an object exists in a queryset using conditional expression

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a queryset like

```
prefetch = Prefetch('site_user',
                            queryset=UserMaster.objects.only("id","nickname")

sites = SiteMaster.objects.filter(query).only("id",
                                                                         "name",
                                                                         "site_url",
                                                                         "status",
                                                                         "created_date",
                                                                         "updated_date") \
            .prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

The result is

sites[0] =

```
{'id': 26, 'name': 'スヱ_______778', 'site_url': 'site-------777',
'status': 1,'flag': True, '_prefetched_objects_cache': {'site_user':
<QuerySet [<UserMaster: UserMaster object (3)>, <UserMaster:
UserMaster object (2)>, <UserMaster: UserMaster object (1)>]>}
```

The field site_user is a list of user objects. I wanted to annotate a field 'flag' to this queryset based on the condition that 'site_user' contains a particular user object.

I tried this but its not working, Can someone please help me out on how to solve this

```
user = request.user
_sites = sites.annotate(flag=
            Case(
                When(Q(site_user=user), then=False),
                default=True,
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```

Models:

```
class UserMaster(models.Model):
        user_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        authority = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=AUTHORITY, default="1")
        version = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        created_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class SiteMaster(models.Model):
            client = models.ForeignKey("ClientMaster", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
            name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
            site_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
            site_user = models.ManyToManyField("UserMaster", blank=True, through="SiteUser")
        
class SiteUser(models.Model):
            site = models.ForeignKey(
                  "SiteMaster", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="users"
                    )
            user = models.ForeignKey(
                  "UserMaster", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the annotation on your prefetch queryset like this:

```
prefetch = Prefetch(
    'site_user',
    queryset=UserMaster.objects.annotate(
        flag=Case(
                When(Q(site_user=user), then=False),
                default=True,
                output_field=BooleanField(),
            )
        )
    ).only("id","nickname","flag")
)
```

Comment: 'site_user' is not a field in UserMaster. So I cannot filter using Q(site_user=user) on UserMaster.

Comment: Ah so what is the relationship of `UserMaster` and `site_user`?

Comment: pls check I have updated Models

Comment: Since you seem to be using `request.user`, where is the FK for the user model? Is it `UserMaster. user_id`?

Comment: If so, you can just do: `When(Q(user_id=user.id)`

Comment: thank you so much fort he help so far, can you please guide me as to how I can understand the magic behind django ORM. I wanted to know how the orm query turns into sql query. I've been reading code in django/db/models/query but its very difficult to understand.